# Copiar e colar célula quando for alterada

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba

Estou começando a usar o VBA com o pacote office, como ainda conheço pouco estou tendo dificuldades para pegar esta funcionalidade.

Estava tentando fazer algo simples e precisava de ajuda para entender como funciona:

Preciso que se uma célula for alterada, o conteúdo dela seja copiada para outra automaticamente, sem ter que clicar em nenhum botão, ex:

Tenho a célula A1:B5

Todas as células estão em branco, se eu preencher qualquer informação na célula A1, preciso que o valor dela seja copiado para a célula B1, se eu alterar a célula A2, preciso que seja alterado o valor para a célula B2 e assim por diante.

Sei que dá pra fazer isso com fórmulas, mas preciso da sintaxe do VBA para começar a fazer algo mais avançado.

Comment: Uma solução é essa, caso necessite rapidamente do código, certamente tem uma solução caso você programe.
Vai na barra de _Desenvolvedor_ do _Excel_ e vai em _gravar Macro_.
Depois solucione o seu problema e utilizando fórmula e **pare** a gravação.
Por fim edite a ´Macro´ gravada e **pegar** o código contido nela.

Comment: Use os eventos do Excel, como o `Worksheet_Change`, que é acionado quando há alguma mudança na planilha desejada. Depois programe uma condição `If`, que se o `Target` for na coluna **A**, o valor desta será copiada para a coluna **B**.

Comment: Se `B1` fica com o conteúdo de `A1` porque não simplificar e colocar em `B1` a formula `=A1` ?

Answer (score 2):

#### Inserir código de Evento

Utilizar o evento `Worksheet_Change`, em que este deverá ser colocado dentro da planilha em que os dados se encontram.
Por Exemplo, no meu caso foi em Planilha1:

[image: Planilha1]

#### Código para uma célula

O código é acionado toda vez que a planilha possui alguma alteração e possui uma condicional que se a alteração for realizada na coluna A, então copia os valores.

```
 Option Explicit
    Private Const B As Long = 2                  '<-- Coluna B
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo CleanExit
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Dim Coluna As Long                           '<-- Coluna selecionada
    Dim linha As Long

    Coluna = Target.Column
    'Se ocorrer mudanças na coluna A
    If Coluna = 1 Then
        linha = Target.Row
        Cells(linha, B) = Cells(linha, Coluna)
    End If

CleanExit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

#### Código para múltiplas células

```
Option Explicit
    Private Const B As Long = 2                  '<-- Coluna B
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo CleanExit
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Dim Coluna As Long                           '<-- Coluna selecionada
    Dim linha As Long
    Dim Area
    Coluna = Target.Column

    'Caso mais de uma célula seja alterada
    If Target.Count > 1 And Coluna = 1 Then
        Dim rng As Range
        Set rng = Range(Target.Address)
        For Each Area In rng.Areas
            Area.Offset(, 1).Value = Area.Value
        Next
        GoTo CleanExit
    End If
    'Se ocorrer mudanças na coluna A
    If Coluna = 1 And Target.Count = 1 Then
        linha = Target.Row
        Cells(linha, B) = Cells(linha, Coluna)
    End If

CleanExit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```