# Copiar celulas ao identificar alteração Worksheet_Change (Excel VB)

Tags: excel-vba

Sou novo em VB e estou tentando fazer com que seja executada uma operação que copia algumas informações da planilha "Controle Backup Clientes" para a planilha "LOG". 
O processo será assim:
o Excel ao detectar alteração em qualquer célula da coluna N da planilha "Controle Backup Clientes", deveria copiar o respectivo valor da coluna A (chamada codigo cliente) e colar na próxima linha em branco da planilha "LOG", onde ficara registrado todas as alterações feitas.[image: No caso da Imagem, as próximas colunas tais, como Data de Alteração ira utilizar a função =HOJE(), Data Correção será o mesmo valor que foi inserido na coluna N]

Abaixo segue o código que fiz, porém toda vez apresenta erro de "Objeto Obrigatório" e não consigo achar o problema

```
Dim celChave As Range
Dim codCliente As Long

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    'celChaves onde fica guardado as celulas que serão alteradas
    Set celChave = Sheets("Controle Backup Clientes").Range("N2:N1048576")

    If Not Application.Intersect(celChave, Range(Target.Address)) _
           Is Nothing Then

        codCliente = Sheets("Controle Backup Clientes").Select(0, 1)
        Sheets("LOG").Select(1048576, 1).End(x1Up).Offset(1, 0).Paste
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Sheets(Sheets("LOG").Select(1048576, 1).End(x1Up).Offset(0, 1)).FormulaR1C1 = "=TODAY()"
        Sheets(Sheets("LOG").Select(1048576, 1).End(x1Up).Offset(0, 2)).Paste = codCliente


        MsgBox "CORREÇÃO SALVA NO LOG! CELULA (" & Target.Address & ")"

    End If 
End Sub
```

Comment: Veja [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/255233/75104), evite [o uso do select](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10717999/7690982) e em qual linha o erro é apresentado?

Comment: Outro detalhe: `Range(Target.Address)` parece-me uma redundância, pois `Target` já é uma `Range`. Além disso, como Daniel já pontuou, é essencial dizer em que linha o erro aconteceu. Rodei aqui no Excel e só deu erro nos `Selects`, por causa da sintaxe inválida, mas não foi objeto obrigatório (foi chamada ruim de método).

Comment: Obrigado @danieltakeshi pela dicas, me ajudou muito!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salve,

Depois de muita pesquisa e estudo, consegui resolver meu problema. Vou explicar mais detalhado o problema e a solução.

Tenho duas planilhas, uma Clientes(trago essa listagem de um banco em SQL), onde tem os dados gerais do cliente(codcli, nome, cnpj, etc), e a outra é a planilha Log.
O que ocorre é que na planilha Clientes eu tenho a coluna N onde insiro uma data, referente a que dia o problema do cliente foi corrigido. O que eu precisava era que quando fosse inserido esta informação na coluna N, iria pegar o código do cliente(coluna A) da respectiva linha, data de hoje(Now), o valor inserido na celula da coluna N e o usuário, ir para a planilha "LOG" e gravar as informações na respectiva sequencia a partir da coluna A e na próxima linha disponível. Abaixo segue o código que realiza exatamente isso.

```
Public wsLog As Worksheet
Public nUsu As String

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("N1:N1048576")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim Rng As Range
        Set wsLog = Sheets("LOG")
        Dim codCli As Variant
        Set Rng = wsLog.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        If nUsu = "" Then
            nUsu = InputBox("Digite seu nome!")
            MsgBox "Olá " & nUsu & "!"
        End If
        codCli = Target.Offset(, -13).Value
        With Rng
            .Value = codCli
            .Offset(, 1).Value = Now
            .Offset(, 2) = Target.Value
            .Offset(, 3) = nUsu
        End With
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Su
```

b

Fiz tambem umas validações, por exemplo se ao alterar a celula na coluna N e nUsu(armazena o nome do usuario) estiver vazia, abre uma inputbox para inserir o nome.
Ainda vou implementar outras coisas, como pedir usuario e senha ao abrir a planilha para ter uma seguranca maior mas isso precisa um pouco mais de estudo rs.

Espero que ajude alguém aí. Abraço