# Filtrar tabela dinâmica por palavra em uma célula

Tags: excel-vba, filter

Este outro logo abaixo da mesma postagem do link acima ..tem diferença em execução ? ... https://stackoverflow.com/a/43139189/9948374

Existe forma de acelerar a execução de algum destes códigos .. Tipo formato binário ... ou alteração n código mesmo.. ?

Coloquei um botão para executar .. pois com

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Assim que eu coloco a primeira letra ele já começa a executar .. isso deixa a planilha "pesada" ... gostaria se não for com um botão fosse ao dar enter na célula "C18" .. (Ao final de cada palavra buscada).

@danieltakeshi, gostaria que ao apagar a célula.. ("C18") = Empty .. aparecesse no lugar "Faça a busca por endereço aqui".. executasse ClearAllFilters... no caso a célula ("C18") sempre que não tiver busca pra fazer terá "Faça a busca por endereço aqui".

mas o filtro tem se comportado desta forma com o código... seleciona o ultimo item do filtro com buscas de texto que não tem entre as opções.

Está assim..

```
Option Compare Text

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42929493/filter-items-with-certain-text-in-a-pivot-table-using-vba
    Dim PvtTbl      As PivotTable
    Dim PvtItm      As PivotItem
    Dim f           As String

    On Error GoTo Sair
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With
    If Target.Address = "$C$18" Then
        f = Target.Value

        ' set the pivot table
        Set PvtTbl = PivotTables("Tabela dinâmica9")
            PvtTbl.ManualUpdate = True
        With PvtTbl.PivotFields("Conteúdo variável 5")
            .ClearAllFilters

            For Each PvtItm In .PivotItems
                If PvtItm.Name Like "*" & f & "*" Then
                    PvtItm.Visible = True
                Else
                    PvtItm.Visible = False


                End If
            Next PvtItm
        End With

    End If
Sair:
    Set PvtTbl = PivotTables("Tabela dinâmica9")
    PvtTbl.ManualUpdate = False
    Debug.Print Err.Number
    On Error GoTo 0
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    End With
End Sub
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
textoDigitado = Range("$C$18").Text
Call PreencheLista
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
'Ao iniciar o formulario ira chamar o procedimento PreencheLista
Call PreencheLista
End Sub


Private Sub PreencheLista()
textoDigitado = TextBox1.Text
'código que irá filtrar os nomes
Dim linha As Integer
Dim TextoCelula As String
linha = 1
'limpa os dados do formulário
ListBox1.Clear
'Irá executar até o último nome
While ActiveSheet.Cells(linha, 1).Value <> Empty
'pega o nome atual
TextoCelula = ActiveSheet.Cells(linha, 1).Value
'quebra a palavra atual pela esquerda conforme a quantidade de letras digitadas e compara com o texto digitado
If InStr(UCase(TextoCelula), UCase(textoDigitado)) > 0 Then
'se a comparação for igual será adicionado no formulario
ListBox1.AddItem ActiveSheet.Cells(linha, 1)
End If
linha = linha + 1
Wend
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Range("C18").Value = Empty Then
Range("C18").Value = "Faça a busca por endereço aqui"
Call ClearReportFiltering

 Else
 End If
End Sub
```

ClearReportFiltering é .. Macro para .ClearAllfilter na Fileds na TD 
(Foi a forma que encontrei por enquanto)[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Adicione também seu código como ele está, o que já tentou?

Comment: `Sheets("Dashboard")` é o nome da Planilha em que está a tabela, `PivotTables("PivotTable1")` é o nome da tabela , `PivotFields("TLEG")` nome do campo da tabela, `Sheets("Dashboard").Range("Lane1").Value` célula com o valor a ser procurado

Comment: Você está colocando o código na planilha em que deseja que o evento seja ativado? [Como está explicado nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/255233/75104). Pois o evento `Worksheet_Change` está sendo usado.

Comment: Depois de muito pesquisar ... Esse código faz exatamente o que preciso ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42929493/filter-items-with-certain-text-in-a-pivot-table-using-vba.                        Quero alterar as linhas....                                                               f = InputBox("Type the text you want to filter:")

If Not pi.Name Like "*" & f & "*" Then.                                                       Quero substituir por uma célula específica ($C$18) ... Para fazer a busca dos itens do filtro.

Comment: @AndréMachado Veja o edit na parte do Evento de Worksheet_Change

Comment: @danieltakeshi .. Gostaria de agradecer muitíssimo pelas sua colaboração em realizar a conclusão deste projeto.

Estou a meses nele, e tive que deixar de lado por um tempo ... mas depois das suas sugestões funciona com excelência.

Sou iniciante em VBA ... Estes códigos que te mostrei foi o mais perto que consegui encontra na rede.

Sei que é um código pesado, mas qualquer nova sugestão sua para melhora-lo.. e agilizar sua finalidade de Buscar filtros ... será muito bem vinda.

Mais uma vez agradeço muitíssimo pela seu tempo gasto em me ajudar.

Comment: @AndréMachado Tabelas Dinâmicas são lentas, eu recomendaria a utilização de Vetores (Arrays), que é mais complexo,ou Autofiltro normal de tabela. Você pode otimizar também para a planilha não realizar cálculos automáticos, somente quando todas alterações forem realizadas, você ativa os cálculos somente uma vez manualmente. Há tutoriais de como realizar isto na internet. De resto, para otimizar é necessário um entendimento mais avançado do VBA e da aplicação mesmo. Com estudos é possível ou você pode postar no CodeReview. Porém leia [isso](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1954) antes

Comment: @danieltakeshi.. editei a publicação .. Ao aplicar a busca de um item que não tem no filtro.. puxa sempre o ultimo item dos filtros. Coloquei no topo do código .. Option Compare Text .. isto resolve a diferença entre maiúsculas e minusculas ? O que pode ser feito nas palavras com acentos.. André tem acento .. mas se buscar Andre sem acento a busca não encontra ? 
Última ideia que me ocorreu foi... este código ...

Comment: @AndréMachado Quando um valor que não existe é inserido, o erro `Não é possível definir a propriedade Visible da classe PivotItem` aparece, então o último item em que ocorreu o erro será mostrado, não é necessariamente o último item. E a palavra precisa conter algo exato utilizando o Wilcard com `If PvtItm.Name Like "*" & f & "*" Then`, caso deseje algo diferente tente utilizar RegEx ou veja mais informações sobre o operador `Like` ou `Wildcards`. Ou uma função pode ser escrita para comparar a String letra por letra e ignorar acentuações.

Comment: @danieltakeshi.. 
Private Sub PreencheLista()...
É muito eficiente em fazer as buscas da coluna a .... Imaginei em pegar os resultados da busca que estão na ListBox ... (Ativo opçao Multselect) e seleciono na ListBox dentre as opções que apareceram quais eu quero.

OU...

Pegar todos os resultados um por um e aplicar eles no filtro da TD...

É possível ... O que acha ?

Comment: @AndréMachado Esta pergunta está ficando muito extensa, sugiro realizar outra pergunta sobre a possibilidade do ListBox. Use sempre a tática de dividir para conquistar para solucionar problemas de programação.

Comment: @danieltakeshi .. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/308932/116347.. novo tópico.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como foi dito no comentário, o código desejado é o [deste link do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42929674/7690982)

#### Dados de Exemplo

Para esta Tabela de exemplo:

[image: Tabela]

#### Resultado

Este é o resultado esperado:

[image: Resultado]

#### Código

```
Option Explicit

Sub FilterCstomers()
'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42929493/filter-items-with-certain-text-in-a-pivot-table-using-vba
    Dim PvtTbl      As PivotTable
    Dim PvtItm      As PivotItem
    Dim f           As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("tabela")
    
    f = ws.Range("C18")

    ' set the pivot table
    Set PvtTbl = ws.PivotTables("Tabela dinâmica1")

    With PvtTbl.PivotFields("campo")
        .ClearAllFilters

        For Each PvtItm In .PivotItems
            If PvtItm.Name Like "*" & f & "*" Then
                PvtItm.Visible = True
            Else
                PvtItm.Visible = False
            End If
        Next PvtItm
    End With

End Sub
```

Em que o nome da Planilha no exemlo é `tabela`, a célula com o filtro é a `C18`, o nome da tabela dinâmica é `Tabela dinâmica1` e o nome do campo desejado é `campo`.

Para verificar os dados da tabela, clicar com o botão direito e seguir a imagem abaixo:

[image: Verificar dados da tabela]

### Evento de Worksheet_Change

Para alterar o filtro da tabela ao mudar a célula `C18`, utilizar o evento `Worksheet_Change`, em que este deverá ser colocado dentro da planilha em que os dados se encontram. No meu caso a Planilha `tabela` ou `Planilha3`:

[image: Árvore VBAProject]

#### Código

No link do SOen, a diferença entre o código do Shai Rado para o código do jeffreyweir. É que há as etapas de desabilitar os cálculos automáticos das células, que podem causar lentidão. Principalmente se estiver dentro do evento `Worksheet_Change`. Para mais informações de otimização, refira ao [CPearson](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/optimize.htm).

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42929493/filter-items-with-certain-text-in-a-pivot-table-using-vba
    Dim PvtTbl      As PivotTable
    Dim PvtItm      As PivotItem
    Dim f           As String

    On Error GoTo Sair
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With
        ' set the pivot table
        Set PvtTbl = PivotTables("Tabela dinâmica1")
        PvtTbl.ManualUpdate = True
    If Target.Address = "$C$18" And Target = vbNullString Then
        PvtTbl.PivotFields("campo").ClearAllFilters
        Target = "Faça a busca por endereço aqui"
    ElseIf Target.Address = "$C$18" And Target <> vbNullString Then
        f = Target.Value


        With PvtTbl.PivotFields("campo")
            .ClearAllFilters

            For Each PvtItm In .PivotItems
                If PvtItm.Name Like "*" & f & "*" Then
                    PvtItm.Visible = True
                Else
                    PvtItm.Visible = False
                End If
            Next PvtItm
        End With

    End If
Sair:
    Set PvtTbl = PivotTables("Tabela dinâmica1")
    PvtTbl.ManualUpdate = False
    Debug.Print Err.Description
    On Error GoTo 0
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    End With
End Sub
```