# Filtrar tabela dinâmica do (Power Pivot) por ListBox

Tags: select, vba, excel-vba, pivot, powerpivot

Este código: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/309087/116347

Faz a seleção na ListaBox ... e Filtra acionado por um botão.. como descrito no link...

Mas se a Tabela dinâmica for criada pelo Power Pivot .. Esse código não se aplica...

É possível fazer esse mesmo trabalho nesta tabela criada..

Agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi desta forma:

Uma formula nomeada pra descobrir a ultima linha preenchida de uma coluna.. e depois ... crie um intervalo nomeado dinâmico com a formula "última" feita anteriormente...como mostro abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Utilizo uma Listbox pra filtrar por palavra entre as opções.
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/309087/116347

**Personalizei conforme minha necessidade**

A Cada vez que limpo o campo de busca Range("$C$18").. Limpa a Range "Selecionados".

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

TextBox1 = Range("E18").Text

If Range("$E$18").Value = Empty Then
Range("$E$18").Value = "Faça a busca por endereço aqui"

Call ClearReportFiltering

Else
End If

If Range("$E$18").Value = "Faça a busca por endereço aqui" Then

Plan1.Columns(2).ClearContents

Else
End If
End Sub
```

**Macro pra Limpar o filtro da TD**

```
Sub ClearReportFiltering()
'PURPOSE: How to clear the Report Filter field

Dim pf As PivotField

Set pf = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Tabela dinâmica9").PivotFields("[Base 1].[Endereço].[Endereço]")

'Option 1: Clear Out Any Previous Filtering
  pf.ClearAllFilters

  End Sub
```

**Macro Pra filtrar**

```
Sub Filtrar()
Dim pf As PivotField
Dim myArray() As Variant
Dim myR As Range

Set myR = Range("Selecionados")
Set pf = Sheets("Geral").PivotTables("Tabela dinâmica9").PivotFields("[Base 1].[Endereço].[Endereço]")


ReDim myArray(0 To myR.Cells.Count - 1)

'Populate the array

For i = 0 To myR.Cells.Count - 1
myArray(i) = "[Base 1].[Endereço].&[" & myR.Cells(i + 1).Value & "]"
Next i

pf.VisibleItemsList = myArray

End Sub
```

Ao acionar um botão com este código a baixo ..

**Macro pra levar os itens selecionados da Listbox pra coluna "B" e chamar o fitro da TD Power Pivot**

```
Sub ClickColuna()


Sheets("Geral").Select

If Range("B2").Select = "" Then
Else

Range("B2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.ClearContents
Range("B2").Select

End If

Dim i As Long
Dim J As Long
Dim arrItems()
    ReDim arrItems(0 To ListBox1.ColumnCount - 1)
    For J = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
        If ListBox1.Selected(J) Then

            For i = 0 To ListBox1.ColumnCount - 1
                arrItems(i) = ListBox1.Column(i, J)
            Next i

            With Sheets("Geral")
                .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(, ListBox1.ColumnCount).Value = arrItems


            End With
        End If
    Next J

Call Filtrar

End Sub
```