# Como faço para fazer aparecer uma lista de clientes em uma busca a partir do nome, no Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Tenho uma lista de clientes; quero fazer uma busca onde se digita parte do nome do cliente e então aparecem todos os clientes que possuem aquele nome. Exemplo:

Razão Social dos Clientes:
João da Silva ME;
Mariazinha Me;
João Vitor ME;
...

Busca desejada: João

O resultado deve aparecer todos os clientes que possuem João na razão social.
Como faço isso no Excel?

Comment: [Relacionada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/309087/75104)

Comment: @danieltakeshi ótima sugestão!

Answer (score 2):

Dependendo do contexto em que está sua tabela poderá utilizar de diversas formas para buscar essas informações.

Sugiro utilizar tabelas do Excel para facilitar inclusive a entrada de dados:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Caso tenha dúvida como criar no youtube tem vários tutoriais para isso ou clique [aqui](https://excelguru.com.br/excel-2/tabelas/)

Após ter sua tabela basta utilizar o filtro para pesquisa por nome...

Conforme indica abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora... caso esteja utilizando macro poderá criar uma macro para ajudar nessa pesquisa, de maneira bem simplória seria algo do tipo:

```
Function Pesquisar(ByVal TEXTO_A_SER_PESQUISADO As String)
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Tabela1").Range.AutoFilter _
            Field:=1, _
            Criteria1:="=*" & TEXTO_A_SER_PESQUISADO & "*", _
            Operator:=xlAnd
End Function
```

E utilizando o exemplo da imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Coloque esse código na *Worksheet_Change*:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then
        Pesquisar (Target.Text)
    End If

End Sub
```

[Segue uma planilha de exemplo.](https://files.fm/u/5p3b9csa)

Ou se tiver utilizando formulário poderá utilizar essa macro para preencher um *combobox* com o resultado de sua pesquisa.

[Tem um módulo completo para trabalhar com tabelas do Excel disponível aqui.](https://github.com/evertramos/excel-modules/blob/master/m_f_Tabelas_Excel)

Espero ter ajudado!