# VBA - Limpar Automaticamente a informação de determinada célula - Evento Change

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

O script abaixo faz com que ao selecionar a coluna **"H11"** limpe automaticamente a coluna **"I11"**.

Como faço para que a mesmo script apague a celula I12 ao selecionar a celula H12 e assim seguindo a mesma logica ate a linha 5000?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

  If Target.Address = "$H$11" Then
      Range("I11").ClearContents

  End If

End Sub
```

[image: Exemplo: lista de seleção:]
[image: Exemplo: lista apos selecionar]

Comment: Você quer selecionar a coluna h11 e excluir da I11 a I5000, ou você quer que ao clicar na linha h12 e excluir i12?

Comment: Quero selecionar a coluna h12 e excluir i12

Comment: Então o que seria replicar até a coluna 5000? [edit] a pergunta com mais informações.

Comment: editado .. consegue ajudar ?

Comment: so uma duvida, voce ja tentou autofiltro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A resposta é similar à resposta: [Copiar e colar célula quando for alterada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/252830/copiar-e-colar-c%c3%a9lula-quando-for-alterada/255233#255233)

Porém, ao invés de copiar e colar, deve-se limpar a célula.

#### Inserir código de Evento

Utilizar o evento `Worksheet_Change`, em que este deverá ser colocado dentro da planilha em que os dados se encontram.
Por Exemplo, no meu caso foi em Planilha1:

[image: Planilha1]

#### Código para uma célula

O código é acionado toda vez que a planilha possui alguma alteração na coluna H, em que a célula em I é limpa com `.ClearContents`

```
Option Explicit
Private Const H As Long = 8                      '<-- Coluna 8 ou H
Private Const I As Long = 9                      '<-- Coluna 9 ou I
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo CleanExit
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Dim coluna As Long                           '<-- Coluna selecionada
    Dim linha As Long

    coluna = Target.Column
    linha = Target.Row
    'Se ocorrer mudanças na coluna H
    If coluna = H Then
        Cells(linha, I).ClearContents
    End If

CleanExit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

#### Código para múltiplas células

Este código irá realizar a ação de limpar a coluna ao lado da célula que foi alterada na coluna H.
Mesmo que sejam realizadas alterações em múltiplas células ou se o intervalo seja um intervalo de células não contíguas.

[image: Resultado]

```
Option Explicit
Private Const H As Long = 8                      '<-- Coluna 8 ou H
Private Const I As Long = 9                      '<-- Coluna 9 ou I
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo CleanExit
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Dim Coluna As Long                           '<-- Coluna selecionada
    Dim linha As Long
    Dim Area
    Dim rng As Range

    Coluna = Target.Column
    'Caso mais de uma célula seja alterada
    If Target.Count > 1 And Coluna = H Then
        Set rng = Range(Target.Address)
        For Each Area In rng.Areas
            Area.Offset(, 1).ClearContents
        Next
        GoTo CleanExit
    End If
    'Se ocorrer mudanças na coluna H
    If Coluna = H And Target.Count = 1 Then
        linha = Target.Row
        Cells(linha, I).ClearContents
    End If


CleanExit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```